# Picking pawns from pouch

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

You have a pouch containing 4 chess pawns. Your prior knowledge is that the pouch does
not contain exactly 2 black and 2 white pieces. All other proportions of colours are equally
probable (e.g. 3 black and 1 white is equally probable as 4 black pieces).

The first piece drawn from the bag is black. What is the probability that the next piece drawn is also black?

I tried solving this problem in the following way:

> The states can be represented by the number of black pieces in the pouch and is then written as:
> $$B = \{0,1,3,4\}$$
> , with probability distribution
> $$P = \{\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}\}$$.
> The possible states of a measurement are picking up a black piece or picking up a white one. We denote these states as
> $$C = \{b, w\}$$
> The first measurement has a probability distribution of
> $$Q = \{q_{b}, q_{w}\} = \{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\}$$
> where we are equally likely to pick up a white or a black piece. This is due to the weighted sum of black and white pieces in the possible states being equal. Let's say we pick a black piece.
> Now reevaluate the probabilities of the states $B$. This can be done by counting in how many ways we could have picked a black piece from each state and weighting the probabilities by that number.
> $$P|b = \{0,\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{4}{8}\}$$
> From these probabilities we can once again do a weighted sum of black and white pieces. It's a bit more complicated this time so I'll write it out.
> $$b_{sum} = 0\cdot-1+\frac{1}{8}\cdot 0 +\frac{3}{8}\cdot 2 +\frac{4}{8}\cdot 3 = \frac{18}{8} = \frac{9}{4}$$
> $$w_{sum} = 0\cdot4+\frac{1}{8}\cdot 3 +\frac{3}{8}\cdot 1 +\frac{4}{8}\cdot 0 = \frac{6}{8} = \frac{3}{4}$$
> $$Q|b = \{q_b|b, q_w|b\} = \{\frac{b_{sum}}{b_{sum} + w_{sum}}, \frac{w_{sum}}{b_{sum} + w_{sum}}\} = \{\frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{4}\}$$

This result was so unintuitive to me that I had to doubt the logic of my reasoning. I tried redoing the calculations with a bag of pieces where the state of two black and two white was allowed and got a similar result of black being much more likely as the second pick if it was the first. Is this correct? How can it be understood in relation to 4 uncorrelated chess pawns in a bag where each measurement would have a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ to be true?

Comment: If the first one is black, you either have one black or three black, each is equally probable .

Comment: This should not be surprising.  Take the more extreme case where you are told that all the pawns are the same color.  If you draw a black one the chance the second one is black is $1$ because you know you started with four black ones.  Does that help the intuition?

Comment: It does Ross Millikan!

Comment: But since the probability is skewed even if  we allow all possible combinations it does not tell the full story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be drawing without replacement.

Let us consider three possible prior distributions for starting with $b_4=0,1,2,3,4$ black balls in a bag:

- $p_1(b_4) = \left(\frac14,\frac14,0,\frac14,\frac14\right)$ - your problem
- $p_2(b_4) = \left(\frac15,\frac15,\frac15,\frac15,\frac15\right)$ - allowing a $2+2$ bag
- $p_3(b_4) = \left(\frac1{16},\frac4{16},\frac6{16},\frac4{16},\frac1{16}\right)$ - binomial if each piece independent

You then happen to draw a Black ball (event $B_1$), which has probability $\mathbb P(B_1 \mid b_4)= \frac{b_4}4$.  Your posterior probabilities are then proportional to $\left(0,\frac1{16},0,\frac3{16},\frac4{16}\right)$ or $\left(0,\frac1{20},\frac2{20},\frac3{20},\frac4{20}\right)$ or $\left(0,\frac4{64},\frac{12}{64},\frac{12}{64},\frac{4}{64}\right)$ which normalised by the probability of $\mathbb P(B_1)=\frac12$ of having drawn a Black ball so they sum to $1$, gives

- $p_1(b_4 \mid B_1) = \left(0,\frac1{8},0,\frac3{8},\frac4{8}\right)$ - your problem
- $p_2(b_4 \mid B_1) = \left(0,\frac1{10},\frac2{10},\frac3{10},\frac4{10}\right)$ - allowing a $2+2$ bag
- $p_3(b_4 \mid B_1) = \left(0,\frac1{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{1}{8}\right)$ - if each piece independent (in effect binomial)

The probability of drawing a second Black piece (event $B_2$) given the first was Black is then

- $\mathbb P_1(B_2 \mid B_1) = \frac1{8}\times \frac03+0\times \frac13 +\frac3{8}\times \frac23+\frac4{8}\times \frac33 = \frac34$ - your problem
- $\mathbb P_2(B_2 \mid B_1) = \frac1{10}\times \frac03+\frac2{10}\times \frac13 +\frac3{10}\times \frac23+\frac4{10}\times \frac33 = \frac23$ - allowing a $2+2$ bag
- $\mathbb P_3(B_2 \mid B_1) = \frac1{8}\times \frac03+\frac3{8}\times \frac13 +\frac3{8}\times \frac23+\frac1{8}\times \frac33 = \frac12$ - if each piece independent

These look intuitively sensible results, as the first problem makes the first draw to be informative about the rest of the bag because the prior distribution is not what you would have if the pieces are independent.

Answer (score 1):

The 4 composition of the pouch are equiprobably thus this is not a parameter we have to consider (anyway nothing changes if you consider it)

You are requested to calculate

$$\mathbb{P}[BB|\text{First Black}]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[BB]}{\mathbb{P}[\text{First Black}]}=\frac{0+0+\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{3}+1}{0+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}+1}=\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: This seems interesting as it is such a short answer but it is not enough for me to understand what you are doing. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @EmilJansson : it is just the definition of conditional probability. The denominator is the probability to get first black: $\frac{1}{4}[0+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{4}{4}]$. The prior probability $\frac{1}{4}$ is equal for any pouch thus it can be omitted because it cannot affect the conditional probability. Hope now it is clear